# If $F(a) \subseteq F(c)$, then $F(c)$ is an extension of $F(a)$

Tags: extension-field

How do I prove the statement above? I have noticed my textbook using it but I cannot find an explanation of why that is true. I can see why this is true in things like $Q(\sqrt[4]{2})$ and $Q(\sqrt{2})$ but that is because I can find the polynomial that makes it an extension. I am pretty sure I have to assume $a,c$ are algebraic but i am not sure. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $F$ is a  [field extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_extension) of $E$ iff $E$ is a subfield of $F$.  That's all you need.  If you want the extension to be algebraic you need to provide more information.

Comment: Just to stress:  not every field extension is algebraic.  $\mathbb C$ is a field extension of $\mathbb Q$ but it is not an algebraic field extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because $F(a)\subseteq F(c)$ implies $F(a)(c)=F(c)$.  After all, $F(c)\subseteq F(c)(a)=F(a,c)=F(a)(c)$.  On the other hand, since $a\in F(c)$ since $F(a)\subseteq F(c)$, so $F(a)(c)=F(a,c)\subseteq F(c)$.

Comment: Thank you, makes sense now.